# how i can pass argument to windows 2003 batch file and execute it from unix-aix and return value to unix-aix

Tags: windows-server-2003, unix, command-line-interface, aix

how i can pass argument to windows 2003 batch file and execute it from unix-aix and return value to unix-aix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this all the time with [nagios](http://www.nagios.org) and [nrpe](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/addons.html) in the windows hosts.

Comment: please you can give me an example ... step by step

Comment: I think that would be very long to do :-). Basically, nagios is monitoring system. From the nagios server you can check things on remote computers (unix/windows), that happens with nrpe. So start reading about nagios and nrpe and decide for yourself if this is what you need.