# how i can execute windows batch file from UNIX-AIX?

Tags: windows-server-2003, unix, command-line-interface, aix, copssh

how i can execute windows batch file from UNIX_AIX i install copssh ???

Comment: how is this question different from your former one: http://serverfault.com/questions/186123/how-i-can-pass-argument-to-windows-2003-batch-file-and-execute-it-from-unix-aix-a/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run Windows Batch files on UNIX / AIX. If you mean that.
If you want to trigger execution, installing openssh (from cygwin maybe) is a good idea.

Comment: NO NO not on unix-AIX .... i want to run command in the windows server itself

Answer (score 0):

Look out Samba client 'net rpc' commands. You can do lot of stuff regarding user management, shares, printers, etc.

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/NetCommand.html

For instance:

> net rpc shell

I don't know if it's script friendly but you can always hack-it a little with expect.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have CopSSH installed, you should be able to shell in and prefix any windows command with cmd /C

```
[Administrator@Computer /cygdrive/c]
$ cmd /C curl
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```